# How to change "Description" in File field to drop down instead of text field?

Tags: 7, files

What is the best way to modify the File field so the "Description" field is a select box instead of a text field. I.e. I want to go from:

[image]

To this:

[image]

I tried a quick experiment, editing the File modules `file.field.inc` file, which resulted in the screenshots above, but if I can avoid forking the File module and instead do it some other way it would be great.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`hook_field_widget_form_alter()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!field.api.php/function/hook_field_widget_form/7) to add your own `#process` callback to the element.

In the callback you can just change the description field from a textfield to a select.

Comment: Awesome, thought there should be a better way. Can you help out with a code example?

Answer (score 1):

Turns out the easiest solution is to use the [Field Collection](http://drupal.org/project/field_collection) module, which allows me to do just what I want.

Comment: Just as an FYI, there's also the [File entity](http://drupal.org/project/file_entity) module, which extends files to become fieldable entities in their own right.

Comment: @Chapabu, thank, I will have to look into that as well.